# Ruby does not recognize times method

Tags: ruby

I wrote a program to simulate the rolling of polyhedral dice but every time I run it I get the error shown below. It displays my prompts and lets me input my numbers, but after that it screws up. I've been trying to find a fix online but I only find people talking about different problems with the `times` method being undefined. I'm new to Ruby, so any help would be appreciated.

**My program:**

```
p = 0
while p < 1
puts "Choose your die type"
die_type = gets.chomp

puts "Choose your number of die"
die_number = gets.chomp

total = 0
i = 1

die_number.times do
  random_int = 1 + rand(die_type)
  total += random_int
  i += 1
end
puts total
end
```

**The error I get:**

```
/dieroll.rb:13: undefined method 'times' for "5":String (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Terminal has nothing to do with interpreting Ruby scripts. Perhaps the problem is in the script itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `die_number = gets.chomp` to `die_number = gets.to_i`. `die_number = gets.chomp`, assigns a string to the local variable `die_number`( Because [`Kernel#gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) gives us a string object). `String` don't have any method called `#times`, rather `Fixnum` class has that method.

Change also `die_type = gets.chomp` to `die_type = gets.to_i`, to avoid the next error waiting for you, once you will fix the first one.

```
1.respond_to?(:times) # => true
"1".respond_to?(:times) # => false
```

In you case `die_number` was `"5"`, thus your attempt `"5".times` raised the error as **undefined method 'times' for "5":String (NoMethodError)**.